# How to manage a time delay (a short time period) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter, raspberry-pi, timedelay

I am working on an Temperature related app using **Python**(with tkinter), **Raspberry Pi** with **DS18B20** Temperature Sensor. The basic requirement of app is

- Display the temperature in every **3sec** and check if temperature crossed over a threshold limit (say **10C**) for continue **10min** it should activate the A/C relay.

The code is working fine to display the temperature (in every 3sec) and activate the A/C relay, but I am unable to manage the 10min waiting window.

I am new to Python, so any help regarding the same would be appreciate.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share the actual code, the only thing I can do is to describe what your strategy might be:

1. Create a variable called `start_timestamp`. Even before the first temperature check, assign the current time to it.
2. Every time you check that the current temperature is lower than or equal 10C, set `start_timestamp` to the current time once again.
3. Every time you check that the current temperature is higher than 10C, do nothing with `start_timestamp`.
4. After every temperature check, compare the current time to (`start_timestamp` plus 600 seconds). If it's greater, it means the last time the temperature turned out to be lower than 10C was at least 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks @Buzzy, you shared the exactly what I want, I implemented it into code segment and its working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim that you can update the temperature measurement every 3 seconds, assuming `update_every_3_seconds` is the function to do that, add:

```
high_temp_seconds = 0
...

def update_every_3_seconds():
    ...
    global high_temp_seconds
    if high_temp:
        high_temp_seconds += 3
    else:
        high_temp_seconds = 0
    if high_temp_seconds >= (10 * 60):
       activate_AC_relay()
```